# Умные отступы в vim

Tags: vim

Есть ли какой-нибудь способ заставить vim реагировать на `tab` двумя различными способами?

1. Вставлять обычный tab, если курсор находится в районе отступов (до первого символа в строке).
2. Вставлять пробелы, если курсор находится в зоне выравнивания.

В итоге должна получаться следующая картина (табы помечены как "`--->`", пробелы, как "`_`").

```
foo() {
--->int_a_____=_2;
--->int_count_=_12;
}
```

Comment: Вот так не пойдёт?

    inoremap <expr> <special> <Tab> (getline('.')[:col('.')-1] =~ '^\s*.\=$' ? "\t" : " ")

Answer (score 2):

Если цель этого - выравнивание в коде по какимто символам(= , ; и т.д.) ТО предлагаю к использованию вот такой плагин [Скринкаст](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/aligning-text-with-tabular-vim/) и [Github](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular)